# Override/Disable Authorization in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, authentication, authorization

I wondered if it is possible to disable/override **all** authorization attributes.

On the development machine, Active directory organization is completely different from production environment's. When I develop/test on development environment I have to "remove" all authorization attributes.

Different types of active directory groups (in **Authorize** attribute) are used in controller action methods.

```
[Authorize]
...

[Authorize(Roles="domain\HR")]
...

[Authorize(Roles="domain\IT")]
...
```

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'd do the following:

1. Write custom authorization attribute which will work as default in Release and always allow action in Debug, i.e.

   ```
   public class MyAuthorizeAttribute: AuthorizeAttribute
   {
       protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
       {
           #if DEBUG
           return true;
           #else
           return base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
           #endif
       }
   }
   ```
2. Replace all existing `Authorize` attributes in code with your own, i.e.

   ```
   [MyAuthorize]
   ...

   [MyAuthorize(Roles="domain\HR")]
   ...

   [MyAuthorize(Roles="domain\IT")]
   ...
   ```
3. Always develop in Debug mode and publish in Release mode

If you don't wish to be bound to Debug/Release thing you can specify your own conditional compilation symbol in project configuration - for example, `DEVTEST` and replace `DEBUG` with `DEVTEST` in step 1 code.

Comment: Hi, I cannot edit it because it is only 1 character, but the base class is mispelled (AuthrorizeAttribute, there's a 'r' after the 'h') and the code does not work properly like it is now. Regards

Comment: @Jaime: Thanks for spotting! Corrected.

Comment: Is this for .Net Core? I don't have an `AuthorizeCore` method available to overide :(

Comment: @Caltor No, my answer is from the time when .NET Core didn't exist yet :) I don't have immediate answer for .NET Core.

Comment: That's OK I'm using .NET Framework. I do have `OnAuthorize` method though. Think the difference might be because I am using Web API rather than MVC.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply add #if like below.

```
#if !DEBUG
[Authorize]
#endif
public class AccountController : BaseApiController
{
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of overriding the `AuthorizeAttribute` have you considered to implement your own?
You can create your attribute and handle the logic for the validation.

Something similar to this:

```
public class AuthorizeRolesAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
  public UserProfileRole[] Roles { get; set; }

  public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
  {
    var profile = ((ETMembershipUser)Membership.GetUser()).Profile;
    if (profile != null)
    {
      foreach (UserProfileRole role in Roles)
      {
        if (role == profile.Role)
          return;
      }
    }
    //throw new SecurityException("You can not access this page");
    RouteValueDictionary redirectTargetDictionary = new RouteValueDictionary();
    redirectTargetDictionary.Add("action", "Index");
    redirectTargetDictionary.Add("controller", "Home");
    filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(redirectTargetDictionary);
  }
}
```

Comment: -1 for very bad idea - to implement custom authorize attribute by NOT deriving from existing AuthorizationAttribute

Comment: @MikeSW, because when you don't derive from AuthorizeAttribute you don't implement the `IAuthorizationFilter` interface. And when you don't do that the order of execution of your filters is different. For example the model binder will run **before** your `pseudo authorization filter` (I call it pseudo because you didn't implement the proper interface so it's not a real authorization filter). I wouldn't go as far as archil and downvote your question, but I completely agree with him that this is a very bad design.

Comment: They are right, I usually use this filter with the AuthorizeAttribute, so I guess I limited the damage of this solution.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov, when I implement a custom auth filter I do implement  IAuthorizationFilter (and it works as it should in my tests). This means I don't have to override the AtuhorizeAttribute just to get that functionality. I agree that in this case the answer didn't account for that interface, but it seems that you don't have to override the AUthorize attribute, only to implement the IAutorizationFilter interface.

Comment: @MikeSW when implementing custom AuthorizationAttribute from scratch, you may have your unauthenticated users see output from cache if you do not take that into consideration. I think it's very bad because AuthorizeAttribute has all its components (AuthorizeCore, HandleUnauthorizedRequest..) virtual and therefore ready to be customized. Why would you need to rewrite everything? And as I read somewhere, "writing security code is skill that very few people possess" :)